# Click on all elements of a class

Tags: javascript, html, css, click

I'm creating a script (pure JS) to click on all elements of a certain class.

```js
function f() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")
  elements.click()
}
//ignore the CSS
```

```css
button {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alert('k')" class="myclass">The function f should click on me!</button>
<button onclick="f()">Click on me for the function f</button>
```

I created this script that should click on all elements with a class of myclass. Why does it not do that?
Thanks!

Comment: getElements is plural  - you need to loop or if only one use `elements[0].click()`

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".myclass").forEach(bt => bt.click());`

Answer (score 1):

Because `getElementsByClassName` always returns an array of elements.

You need to loop through them.

Example:

```
function f(){
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass").forEach(el => el.click())
}
```

Comment: Please do not answer such simple and easily found questions. Instead find a dupe and vote to close. Already answered in the comments too